# 2D list python unable to get it right

Tags: python, arrays, list

im trying to the below code but when I run the function for examnple:

finder("001-987654-003")

Nothing is happening. What went wrong?

```
def finder(lookupvalue):
    user_list = [
        ["Account number","Currency","Balance"],
        ["001-987654-003","USD",1300.72],
        ["001-919202-100","EUR",105.01],
        ["001-905700-100","EUR",305.00],
        ["001-908415-307","CHF",20804.98],
        ["011-974777-200","PLN",208.15],
        ["001-931654-001","USD",450.7]
    ]
    
    for row in user_list:
        if user_list[0][0]==lookupvalue:
            print("yes")
```

Comment: HAve you tried a dictionary?

Comment: You should index your list with respect to `row` variable - `user_list[row][0]`

Comment: @FilipMłynarski `row`is not an index but  one of the inner lists. So it's `row[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
user_list = [
        ["Account number", "Currency", "Balance"],
        ["001-987654-003", "USD", 1300.72],
        ["001-919202-100", "EUR", 105.01],
        ["001-905700-100", "EUR", 305.00],
        ["001-908415-307", "CHF", 20804.98],
        ["011-974777-200", "PLN", 208.15],
        ["001-931654-001", "USD", 450.7]
    ]

def finder(lookupvalue, lookuplist, col_index):
    for row in user_list:
        if row[0] == lookupvalue:
            print(row[col_index-1])
            
            
finder("001-919202-100", user_list, 2)
```

output:

```
EUR
```

Comment: @pucktack you can try this

Comment: pls explain: print(row[col_index-1])
sorry.. im still learning :D

Comment: @pucktack, you say when type col_index =2 get output : EUR, index start from zero in python

Comment: @pucktack if this is correct please accept `answer`

Comment: In truth if you want to get the second item from a list (EUR), the index is 1, 0 being the account number and 2 being the balance. So refering to 2 then substracting 1 was actually a mistake.

Comment: @AdrienLevert, OP say when he send `2` he want get `ERU`

Comment: @user1740577 well yes, but in essence he wants to get the second element (Currency)  and the right way to go about that would be to simply use the actual second index `1`

Comment: Based on my understanding, row[col_index-1]
the col_index will be the assigned variable relating to the position of the index. since it is less 1, then it will refer to the number of list less 1

Comment: @pucktack, thank bro, are you question in your above comment or edit answer?

Comment: @pucktack in a nutshell, 2 is the human language index for second, but 1 is the computer language index, so using the `-1` "translates" to computer index, but that's an unnecessary computation and doing this could cause problems down the road or in other situations

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `row` instead of `user_list`:

```
def finder(lookupvalue, lookuplist, col_index):
    for row in lookuplist:
        if row[0] == lookupvalue:
            print(row[col_index - 1])

finder("001-919202-100", user_list, 2)
```

That's because if you use `user_list[0][0]` in the for loop it'll constantly refer to `"Account number"` whilst `row[0]` will go through the different lists, looking up the account number.

But as one of the comments said, a dictionary would probably be better for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a dictionary:

```
user_list = {
    "Account Number": ["001-987654-003", "001-919202-100", "001-905700-100"],
    "Currency": ["USD", "EUR", "EUR"],
    "Balance": [1300.72, 105.01, 305.00]
}
```

Seems more appropriate in your case as you're trying to store different lists (I think).